# Why the getElementsByTagName is not working in this example

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, getelementsbytagname

I have an DomElement with this content:

```
$cell =  <td colspan=3>
             <p class=5tablebody>
                 <span style='position:relative;top:14.0pt'>
                     <img width=300 height=220 src="forMerrin_files/image020.png">
                 </span>
             </p>
         </td>
```

There, I am geting the p element with:

```
$paragraphs = $xpath->query('.//p', $cell);
```

My goal is to get the img element from the cell element.

I have tried:

```
$paragraph->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0);
```

But I am getting null. Any idea why?

Thank you

Comment: What is returning the var_dump of $paragraph->getElementsByTagName('img') ?

Comment: A DOMNodeList, this is alweys like that, even if the list is empty

Comment: xpath query returns a DOMNodeList, I guess you are iterating over it, so you run getElementsByTagName on DOMNode objects, according to php documentation DOMNode doesn't have a getElementsByTagName function. Can this have something to do with the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you after?

```
$htmlStr = '<td colspan=3>
             <p class=5tablebody>
                 <span style=\'position:relative;top:14.0pt\'>
                     <img width=300 height=220 src="forMerrin_files/image020.png">
                 </span>
             </p>
         </td>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlStr);

$paragraphs = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
var_dump($paragraphs->item(0)->getAttribute('src'));
```

Outputs:

```
string 'forMerrin_files/image020.png' (length=28)
```

Comment: Just tested it in the way you mentioned and it works, but in fact, the problem occures while I am using a different method to extract the $htmlStr. This is obtained from a more complex dom document. I will try to investigate.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of DOMXpath::query() has to be a context node, you can not just use some HTML string. I suggest using DOMXpath::evaluate() anyway. The syntax of both methods is the same, but `query()` is limited to Xpath expressions that return a node list, `evaluate()` allows Xpath expressions that return scalars, too.

```
$html = <<<HTML
  <td colspan=3>
    <p class=5tablebody>
      <span style='position:relative;top:14.0pt'>
        <img width=300 height=220 src="forMerrin_files/image020.png">
      </span>
    </p>
  </td>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

// for each td element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//td') as $cell) {
  // for each img inside a p
  foreach ($xpath->evaluate('.//p//img', $cell) as $img) {
    var_dump($img->getAttribute('src')); 
  }
}
```

Output: https://eval.in/147576

```
string(28) "forMerrin_files/image020.png"
```